# Where should I link the translated questions to?

Tags: support, languages, international-sites

[I translate every question I ask into Spanish and Portuguese, and I should also link to translations to each other](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331334/is-cross-posting-the-same-question-in-different-languages-allowed), similar to how [a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map) has sitelinks to the translated articles.

I had first been linking the translations in the comments, but the comments in all my questions are currently locked for 10 years since I misused the comments. So, where exactly should the translated questions be linked?

Update: Now I have translated this question: [Does C have an equivalent of C++'s cmath library?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77375701/does-c-have-an-equivalent-of-cs-cmath-library).

Comment: I don't really follow what you're asking here. All of your questions are locked from comments, but they can be edited without issue. If you are trying to say that you want to cite the resources you used to try to answer your own question, include those in the question, not the comments.

Comment: It *looks like* you are [cross](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66079316/why-do-primitive-data-types-have-a-fixed-size) [posting](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/547797/por-qu%c3%a9-los-tipos-de-datos-primitivos-tienen-un-tama%c3%b1o-fijo) content on the sites though; cross posted normally isn't well received by the community.

Comment: "_I really cannot live without putting the sitelinks to the translated questions_" I feel that is somewhat of an extreme statement, maybe you should take a break from the Stack Exchange Network for some time? Your life really doesn't depend on translating content and re-posting it on multiple language sites.

Comment: Also, a moderator is unlikely to take such action without warning you first. Are you sure you're telling the whole story?

Comment: Related question on [meta.se]: [Is cross-posting a question on multiple Stack Exchange sites permitted if the question is on-topic for each site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu)

Comment: I would suggest that the user has had some interaction, based on this [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67910418/what-step-can-i-take-to-fix-the-error-of-unknown-type-name-node#comment131164560_67910478) , @41686d6564standsw.Palestine .

Comment: @Larnu Re _"Related question"_: According to [this MSE post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/331334/348196), it's allowed in the case of international sites. I don't think that's the root cause of the OP's problem.

Comment: From what I understand OP cross posted their answered questions to various language specific Stack Overflow sites, folks at [Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/) didn't like it, OP unaccepted the answers here (and  commented something on them?) causing the mods to lock their posts to stop the comments.

Comment: Note that that FAQ says if you find a *useful* question it's fine to translate it and post on on a different site. Here the OP has some (very) poorly received questions that they have then cross posted almost a *year* later, and then (presumably) "advertised" the cross posts on [so], @41686d6564standsw.Palestine .

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Yeah, [it seems there are a lot of things the OP can't live without](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlFcv.png) (this is an auto-translated version of the comments on one of their questions on Stack Overflow en español.

Comment: @Larnu "advertised" What are you talking about?

Comment: As in putting comments to the other language sites for your *identical* questions, @ArunabhBhattacharya .

Comment: And the meta question says "Note that this is about cross-posting *within the network*; what you describe is another, less often seen form. In either case, it's probably a good idea to link the questions to each other (and if you copy a question from someone else, you are even [*required* to provide attribution](/help/referencing)), and if any answers are posted, ask the author to post them on the other site as well or do it yourself (again keeping in mind the attribution rules)."

Comment: *"it's probably a good idea to link the questions to each other"* in the question, not the comments.

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya From what I can gather, it seems that moderators on Stack Overflow en español told you that it's fine to cross-post, and it's even fine to link to the original question, but if you've already got an answer, you should post the translated version as an answer there (obviously, you'd need to provide attribution). It seems like you didn't like that and they closed your question(s) as a result. What did you do after? Did you complain about that in the comments of the SO (English version) posts? Because that's what it looks like.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine And now why has this been closed as needing details of clarity? What details do I need to add?

Comment: *Where can I add the sitelinks?*. That feature doesn't exist. We're not wikipedia and we have no obligation to have all features of all sites across the internet here on Stack Overflow. Before you know it we swipe users to the left or right.

Comment: You've been banned from Wikipedia and previously suspended network-wide from the Stack Exchange network. You've been picking fights with moderators from multiple sites. Your question seems to assume the network will adapt to your wishes, while you misunderstand which features it does and doesn't have. If you do not understand what you did wrong, reply to one of the moderator messages you undoubtedly received in the past asking for specific guidance.

Comment: Arunabh: This question was changed radically from the initial revision. That should not occur on a question that has one or more answers. I think that this question should rolled back, also I think you should make a bigger effort to show that you are open to learn the generally accepted SO practices rather than insist in doing something unusual.

Comment: @Mast "You've been banned from Wikipedia". How do you know about Wikipedia?

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya You asked off-topic questions on stackexchange about your wiki ban....

Comment: @ArunabhBhattacharya - You told us about it.

Comment: You appear to have translated the error message into Spanish yourself, rather than posting an actual error message.  That's not helpful, because no one searching an error message will find that.

Comment: This disregards actual effort from people volunteering to answer questions and moderate the SO sites. If a question already exists somewhere else, the answer is brought as well to SOes, but this exercise made by OP feels more like inflating profiles on multiple places for an unknown purpose (stating something somewhere, using a SO badge as a proof-of-knowledge? Sorry but cannot think of any good reason to actually work this out the way OP intends to).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I don't know if the below will be helpful in the immediate term to add links as comments in your posts due to the comments lock, but it could be interesting to learn about an old initiative to link questions across *Stack Overflow International* sites and Stack Overflow.

A few years ago, a post was made in Stack Overflow en español inviting users to link questions from that site with questions from Stack Overflow. Apparently the tool is still working. You can learn about this in [¿Cómo funciona la asociación de preguntas entre SO y SOes?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3967/65) (How works the question association between SO and SOes)

Other related posts

- [Herramientas de asociación de preguntas entre SO y SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3963/65). This post includes a link to the original post in Russian.

---

Regarding [rev 1](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3963/65)

If you are serious about the fact that you can't live without the way that you are using a Stack Overflow feature, please contact a professional counseling service near to you as we can't help here with such issues.

Having all your questions' comment locked for 10 years is a sign that someone has persisted for a while abusing the questions' comments. According to the comments to the question, it's clear that you were doing that. Stop, period.

If you are really open to discussing the way that you are trying to use Stack Overflow, make a new post explaining what you are trying to achieve and ask for suggestions about how to achieve that.

Comment: I noticed that [someone](https://stackoverflow.com/users/687884/pholser) has added a comment to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66891186/what-step-can-i-take-to-fix-the-warning-of-raw-use-of-parameterized-class-clas). Besides the moderators, who can comment on deleted or locked posts?

Comment: I don't know. Post a new question to give more visility to that.