# Linking the translated questions to each other

Tags: support, linked-questions, international-sites

I have been bludgeoning this for more than a year now.

I first try to link the translated questions to each other in the comments. Everything is fine with the first two questions I ask until I end up in a controversy with the [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67910418/what-step-can-i-take-to-fix-the-error-of-unknown-type-name-node) when a moderator in [Stack Overflow en español][1] says that it is OK to translate the questions and link them to each other, but if I am translating a year-old question that already has an answer, then it is better to post the translated version as the answer there, but [I have some disagreement with the team, so they closed the question as a result, then I try give a more convincing reason for why I need a translation, then later on I try to complain about the closed question in the comments of the English version of the question.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nlFcv.png) Then [Samuel Liew, a moderator in the English version then](https://stackoverflow.com/users/584192/samuel-liew)  decides to lock the comments for a decade. That makes me asks [this meta question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421330/where-should-i-link-the-translated-questions-to).

After that meta question, I use link the questions to each other using this format:

> [Translation in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com/)
>
> [Translation in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/)

However, when I ask the [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77375701/mathematical-functions-in-c), [Abdul Aziz Barkat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14991864/abdul-aziz-barkat) moves the translation links to bottom and makes them smaller to emphasize the actual question more:

> <sub>[Translation in Spanish](https://es.stackoverflow.com)</sub>
>
> <sub>[Translation in Portuguese](https://pt.stackoverflow.com)</sub>

I do the same thing with my other questions. Today [Dharman, one of the moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1839439/dharman) has unlocked the comments and removed the links from the question with the edit comments mentioning:

> This does not belong in the question

but has not given any convincing feedback.

However, [this meta question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331334/is-cross-posting-the-same-question-in-different-languages-allowed) clearly says:

> Note that this is about cross-posting *within the network*; what you describe is another, less often seen form. In either case, it's probably a good idea to link the questions to each other (and if you copy a question from someone else, you are even [*required* to provide attribution](/help/referencing)), and if any answers are posted, ask the author to post them on the other site as well or do it yourself (again keeping in mind the attribution rules).

And answer to the previous question says:

> A few years ago, a post was made in Stack Overflow en español inviting users to link questions from that site with questions from Stack Overflow. Apparently the tool is still working. You can learn about this in [¿Cómo funciona la asociación de preguntas entre SO y SOes?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3967/65) (How works the question association between SO and SOes)
>
> Other related posts
>
> - [Herramientas de asociación de preguntas entre SO y SOes](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3963/65). This post includes a link to the original post in Russian.
>
> ---

I still to need to understand the following:

1. What does the advice from Meta.SE mean when it talks about linking the posts?
2. Do I need to add links to the translated copied anywhere on the original question?

Comment: "*Then Samuel Liew, a regular user in the English version decides to lock the comments for a decade.*" Sam was a moderator at the time the comments were locked. Regular users cannot do that.

Comment: It doesn’t look like most of the links actually point anywhere, so it seems rather pointless to ponder how to add them to posts. Rather you should focus on making each question suitable for the site it is actually on.

Comment: Also, I don’t get how attribution is relevant for all this. The links don’t point to a *source*, they point to multiple translations and these point further in a circular fashion. Attribution would just point to the original for each question, with one at the end pointing nowhere wide because it actually is the first of the questions and this has no source.

Comment: `but has not given any convincing feedback` You already got plenty of feedback before (I've read the previous discussions). The community kind of disagrees with you regarding the necessity to do these translations, and most importantly to me, strongly disagrees about the way you're doing it. My suggestion is *don't work against the system* - please take a break and stop doing stuff that is not needed and not wanted. I understand your frustration, I do, but really, going against the community is not a great idea on this site.

Comment: Voting to leave closed. Please don't submit your question for reopening if you only make minor edits.

Comment: Editing Questions to improve them (e.g. clarification, adding additional information, etc.) *is encouraged*. However, editing a Question to change it into a different question which results in invalidating one or more Answers, is against Stack Exchange policy (even when your original question wasn't what you intended). Your most recent edits here invalidated one or more answers, so they have been rolled back.

Comment: You previous edit had been rolled back by a moderator and they have left a comment explaining why, please don't try to apply the same edits or edits that have the same problem.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It looks like you might have misunderstood the advice from Meta.SE. When it talks about linking the posts, it means that you should not copy the content and pretend that it's yours. Even after you translate it into another language, the original idea wasn't yours, so it would be good idea to mention the original source of the question in the translated question. But please consult Meta site of the target site for more details.

You do not need to add links to the translated copied anywhere on the original question. Not in the comments and not in the question. It's pure noise.

I unlocked the comments as I assumed that after enough time has passed there won't be any more comments discussing the question. I think the lock has fulfilled its purpose.

You asked answerers to repost their answers on the translated questions, but you also did it in a pretty confusing manner. It doesn't make any sense to ask the answerer to repost their answer on the translated question. Most likely, they do not even speak that language. And even if they speak, chances are they don't want to do that. If you want to translate the answers, you can do so yourself, but you need to add proper attribution. This means, you need to add the link to the original and the name of the original author. If the original author asks you to delete it the answer because they want to post it themselves, you should oblige. The original author has the priority to translate their own answer.

Answer (score 15):

What is the value in linking the questions, or the answers? If you are most comfortable in Spanish, use the Spanish site, similarly with Portuguese etc.

#### To answer point 2.

If you've translated a post from Stack Overflow then you [must provide attribution for that post](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/06/25/attribution-required/) when you create it on any other site. It's not mandatory to add any comment on the original site i.e. here, or to edit the original post with links to any translations. That seems to be one of the problems you're running into here.

If you're finding you're not adding attribution in the way that Stack Overflow en español or Stack Overflow em Português wants then you'd need to take it up on the Meta of those sites.

#### To answer point 1.

What [you're quoting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/331334/is-cross-posting-the-same-question-in-different-languages-allowed) from Meta Stack Exchange is general advice, it does not and cannot override the way individual sites want to operate. They are each able to override and contradict that general advice if they want to. If the moderators of a site want you to stop doing something, stop doing it. Perhaps you just need to accept that there is no right way to link translated questions on Stack Overflow because we don't feel it's necessary.